# Best wopt options for large rasters

Tags: r, raster, gdal, large-files, terra

What are the best wopt and gdal options when processing large rasters with `terra::`?
I want to match a raster stack (2.5arcmin) with a raster that has a much higher resolution (500*500m). Workflow: disaggregate as close as possible, then resample and finally mask. This works, but the output tif is > 100gb and the process takes forever.

```
r <- rast("rasterstack_004166deg.tif") 
r_template <- rast("rasterstack_000449deg.tif") 

wopt_options <- list(gdal = c("BIGTIFF=YES",
                              "PREDICTOR = 2",
                              "NUM_THREADS = ALL_CPUS"),
                     tempdir = "/somewhere_I_have_a_lot_of_space",
                     todisk = TRUE)

r_processed <- disaggregate(r, fact = 9) %>% 
  resample(., r_template) %>% 
  mask(., r_template,
       filename = "outputfile.tif",
       wopt = wopt_options)
```

Should the *wopt_options* be placed inside `terra::disaggregate()` and `terra::resample()` as well? Is there any way to reduce the file size and speed up the process?

I also tried the following gdal options `gdal=c("COMPRESS=DEFLATE", "TFW=YES")` or `gdal=c("COMPRESS=LZW", "TFW=YES")`, but nothing really changed. Also tried without any gdal options.

In addition, I also did this with `raster::projectRaster()` function (used disaggregated r) which was much faster and the outputfile.tif was much smaller. However, I guess I should avoid using `projecRaster()` here:

```
beginCluster()
r_processed<- 
  projectRaster(stack(r_disaggregated),
                raster(r_template),
                filename = "outputfile.tif")
endCluster()
```

The r raster looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are some comments that may be of help. The default behavior of `terra` is to set BIGTIFF to true when necessary, so you normally do not need to specify that. Also by default, LZW compression is used so you should see a difference if you set compression to NONE.

To set the `tempdir`, use

```
terraOptions(tempdir="/somewhere_I_have_a_lot_of_space")`
terraOptions()
#memfrac   : 0.6
#tempdir   : /somewhere_I_have_a_lot_of_space
```

You should not set `todisk=TRUE`, that is for debugging only.

Now we have

```
x <- disaggregate(r, fact = 9) 
y <- resample(x, r_template) 
z <- mask(y, r, filename="outputfile.tif", wopt=wopt_options)
```

I split it because that is easier to read and debug. You were masking with `r_template` but that should be with `r`. If you wanted to use the options at all three steps, you would need to use the `wopt` argument each time, not just the last time.

Can you `show(r)` so that I can make a reproducible example?

I am assuming the problem is with `resample` because that is implemented a bit differently but this may have improved with the development version. You can install it like this:

`install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

Comment: Thanks! I see terra's default options have improved! Good to know that x y and z should be calculated separately, I just hope it won't exhaust the RAM or be slower.